# The image will be displayed as many times as entered in the input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I started my adventure with jQuery and in the exercise I encountered an obstacle that I do not know how to deal with.
I have to write a code that will result when you enter a number, the image will be displayed as many times as the user entered.
Input field that accepts only digits (code must be additionally verified). Minimum 1, maximum 100
If not a digit or out of range then we inform the user
The user enters a number and clicks a button, the program displays the above user as many times as the user entered
What is more (do not have to be perfect) 5 pictures to insert a new line (
).
I will be grateful for any help...

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#display').hide();
  $('#danger').hide();

  var src = $('#image').val();
  var number = $('#number').val();

  function showInput() {
      var index = 1;
      for (var index = 0; index < number; index++) {
        document.getElementById('#display').innerHTML =
          document.getElementById("#number").value;
      }
  }
  
  $("#submit").click(function () {
    if (number == "") {
      //Check if number is numeric
      $('#danger').html('Prosimy o wpisanie właściwej wartości').show();
      $("#number").attr("style", "border-color: red!important");
      return false;
      
    } else if (number < 1 || number > 100) {
      $('#danger').html('Prosimy o wpisanie właściwej wartości').show();
      $("#number").attr("style", "border-color: red!important");
      return false;
      
    } else {
      showInput()
      $('#danger').html('Prosimy o wpisanie właściwej wartości').hide();
      $("#number").attr("style", "border-color: ");
    }
  });
  
});
</script>

<body>
    <form>
        <br/>
        <label for="name">Ile razy wyświetli się obrazek</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="number" id="number" placeholder="wpisz liczbę od 1 do 100" required="">
    </form>
    <br/>
    <p>
        <img id='display' src="kaczka.jpg" />
    </p>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="showInput()" >
    <div id="danger" class="alert alert-danger collapse"></div>
    <br/>
    <div id="img"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: The problem could be that while you call `showInput` method, you don't calculate the updated value of `number` variable. Add `number = $('#number').val();` inside click method callback.

Comment: to check if it's a number or string use the typeof operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof then use .clone() https://api.jquery.com/clone/ to clone your image then append it http://api.jquery.com/append/ to the desired node

Comment: hint: `img` tags do not have `innerHTML`. if you want to display an image `x` amount of times, you have to create `x` amount of `img` tags and put them in a wrapper `div` (or `p`)

Answer (score 0):

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4yqqp3m6/

Based on the errors you made, you should continue with something easier to get a real grip of `javascript` and `JQuery`.

So you had multiple problems here - check comments:

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#display').hide();
        $('#danger').hide();


        var src = $('#image').val();
        var number = $('#number').val();

        function showInput(number) { // the same here to get the number

            var index = 1
            for (var index = 0; index < number; index++) {
                document.getElementById('display').innerHTML +=
                   ' <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg" />';
            }

            $('#display').show();
        }



            $("#submit").click(function () {

            //!! this part you missed
            number = $("#number").val(); // get the value from input
                        number = parseInt(number); // number is string cast it to integer
            //!!


             if (number == "") {
                //Check if number is numeric
                $('#danger').html('Prosimy o wpisanie właściwej wartości').show();
                $("#number").attr("style", "border-color: red!important");

                return false;

            } else if (number < 1 || number > 100) {
                $('#danger').html('Prosimy o wpisanie właściwej wartości').show();
                $("#number").attr("style", "border-color: red!important");

                return false;

            } else {

                showInput(number); // you have to give the number to function
                $('#danger').html('Prosimy o wpisanie właściwej wartości').hide();
                $("#number").attr("style", "border-color: ");


            }
        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <form>
        <br/>
        <label for="name">Ile razy wyświetli się obrazek</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="number" id="number" placeholder="wpisz liczbę od 1 do 100" required="">
    </form>
    <br/>

    <!-- this part was wrong too... -->
    <div id='display'>
    </div>


    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"> <!-- dont call show inpout yet -->
    <div id="danger" class="alert alert-danger collapse"></div>
    <br/>
    <div id="img"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a little refactoring of your code. The demo is available at [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/SO4kprhzx1fyAsogqXBR?p=preview).

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var image = document.getElementById('display').outerHTML; // to persist the image
    $('#display').hide();
    $('#danger').hide();

    function showInput(number) {
      $('#displayBox').html(''); // to remove previous images
        for (var index = 0; index < number; index++) {
          $('#displayBox').append(image);
        }
    }

    $("#submit").click(function () {
         var number = parseInt($('#number').val(), 10); // correct way to get a numeric input value
         if (isNaN(number) || (number < 1 || number > 100)) { 
            $('#danger').html('Prosimy o wpisanie właściwej wartości').show();
            $("#number").attr("style", "border-color: red!important");
            return false;
        }  
        showInput(number); // passing the actual number value
        $('#danger').html('Prosimy o wpisanie właściwej wartości').hide();
        $("#number").attr("style", "border-color: ");
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <form>
        <label for="name">Ile razy wyświetli się obrazek</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="number" id="number" placeholder="wpisz liczbę od 1 do 100" required="">
    </form>
    <p id="displayBox"> <!-- that's what I've added to the template, here we will push our images -->
        <img id='display' src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fruits/128/Banana.png" />
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" > <!-- no need to onclick since you have handler binding via js -->
    <div id="danger" class="alert alert-danger collapse"></div>
    <div id="img"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I dont think she's looking for working refactured code... It may be  better to show bad points in her code and point her in the right direction and let her figure out the rest.

Comment: @JTC I tried to reflect it in the code comments, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

made small changes to your code:

css:

```
#display{
    width:20%;
}
```

javascript:

```
<script>
var src = $('#image').val();
var number = $('#number').val();
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#display').hide();
    $('#danger').hide();



    $("#submit").click(function () {
    src = $('#image').val();
    number = $('#number').val();
    console.log(number);

         if (number == "") {
            //Check if number is numeric
            $('#danger').html('Prosimy o wpisanie właściwej wartości').show();
            $("#number").attr("style", "border-color: red!important");

            return false;

        } else if (number < 1 || number > 100) {
            $('#danger').html('Prosimy o wpisanie właściwej wartości').show();
            $("#number").attr("style", "border-color: red!important");

            return false;

        } else {

            showInput()
            $('#danger').html('Prosimy o wpisanie właściwej wartości').hide();
            $("#number").attr("style", "border-color: ");


        }
    });
});

    function showInput() {
        $('#container').empty();
        var index = 1
        for (var index = 0; index < number; index++) {
            $('#container').append("<img id='display' src='image.jpg' />");
        }
    }

</script>
```

html:

```
<body>
    <form>
    <br/>
    <label for="name">Ile razy wyświetli się obrazek</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="number" id="number" placeholder="wpisz liczbę od 1 do 100" required="">
</form>
<br/>
<div id="container">

</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" onclick="showInput()" >
<div id="danger" class="alert alert-danger collapse"></div>
<br/>
<div id="img"></div>
</body>
```